# Data Truncation error in Enum Data type

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, enums

I am new to JSP and to Eclipse

I have a Combo box in a **JSP Page** in which will be like this

```
  <select name="User_type">
   <option value="1">Buyer</option>
   <option value="2">Seller</option>
   </select>
```

I will receive the value in **Servlet** using the request and converting into Integer

```
 int User_type=Integer.parseInt((request.getParameter("User_type")));
```

**Here My Database Structure Is:**

In database i have the data type as enum (**User_type-enum('b','s')**)

**My Insert Query :**

```
insert into signup values('"+User_type+"')
```

My expectation is when the input selected is Buyer,then b should be stored in DB

Whereas it says that **Data Truncation Error** occurs.

Comment: Your JSP page is posting a `1` for Buyer, and your database is expecting a `b`. You don't map `1` to `b` anywhere and you're confused it's not working?

Comment: And please, please!!, stop using string concatenation with user-supplied values to build a SQL statement, unless you *want* you program to fail and/or be hacked by [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Use `PrepareStatement` and parameter markers.

Comment: @Andreas its a enum data type so i am expecting '1' mapped with 'a'  and 2 with b.Is my expectation wrong ??

Comment: Yes, your expectation is wrong. Why would you think that the string literal `'1'` would magically map to the string literal `'a'`. And even if you had been right, you have values `1` and `2` from the JSP, but the enum is expecting `'b'` and `'s'`, so if `1` *had* mapped to `'a'`, it still wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @Andreas sorry i  commented wrongly .its a enum data type so i am expecting '1' mapped with 'b' and 2 with s.                                                                     When i insert it manually using the command(insert into signup values(1)).It is getting stored as b.

Comment: But you're not inserting `1`. You're inserting `'1'`. Not the same thing. And why not use the enum value (`'b'`, `'s'`) instead of the enum index (`1`, `2`)? That way it'll still work correctly if you re-order the enum or add more values. Less error-prone. And it's the value you get back when querying the table.

Comment: @Andreas ya i agree .Got your point .tanx

Comment: Yes, replace `1` and `2` with `b` and `s` in the JSP. Remove `parseInt()`. Change SQL to `insert into signup values(?)`, use `PreparedStatement` and `setString(1, userType)`.